# How to check the Console Output for a specific string and raise an error on the Build?

Tags: jenkins, compiler-errors, hudson, build-server

I have `Hudson` configured for building a project.

And the console output, after building is, as follows:

```
Compiling ./main.py ...
Sorry: IndentationError: ('expected an indented block', ('./main.py', 8, 6, 'thread.start_new_thread( foo.FooThread, () )\n'))
Compiling ./udpReceiver.py ...
<<<<< build finished!
POST BUILD TASK : SUCCESS
END OF POST BUILD TASK : 0

Deleting project workspace... 
done

Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see, I have an Indentation Error....and `Hudson` says that the build job finished with success.

**What I want is something like this:**

Check if the string "*IndentationError*" is presented on the console output text ... if so, than the build should be:
**Finished: FAILED!!!!!!!!**

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure it's compatible with Hudson as I'm using jenkins, but perhaps the [log parser plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) is what you're looking for. Just specify *IndentationError* as an error rule and check the *Mark build failed on Error*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I confirm that the [Log Parser plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) can do the job to change the build status to failure.

Install the plugin and create a rule set for your Python build for example:

[image]

In the create the /var/lib/jenkins/logParserRules/python-error file:

```
error /IndentationError/
```

Next, update the Python build with these settings:

[image]

The build status will be changed to FAILURE:

```
Compiling ./udpReceiver.py ...'
Sorry: IndentationError: ('expected an indented block', ('./main.py', 8, 6, 'thread.start_new_thread( foo.FooThread, () )\n'))
Compiling ./udpReceiver.py ...
Build step 'Console output (build log) parsing' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Comment: Yep, maybe you have to install an older version of this plugin, but the configuration will be identical. If this solution works, don't forget to mark my solution as the good one :)